# Framework for providing API access to website?

Tags: php, api, rest, frameworks

We have a website that we want to provide web based API access to to other sites.

It may end up being a REST based API, but I'm not sure yet. It needs to be accessible from a Drupal module, but we want to built the API to be scalable so that we can access the site's data and functionality from other environments such as joomla, wordpress, other non-php languages, etc.

I am looking for a robust/stable PHP based framework that allows me to create such APIs - can folks suggest something that meets the criteria?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967991/web-service-construction-toolkit-wrapper-for-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [Zend REST Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.server.html) - it's robust, easily extensible and frequently reviewed in community "bug hunts".

- Here's a [tutorial by a Zend guru](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework.html)
- [A getting started guide](http://blog.realmofzod.com/blog/2009/05/06/implement-a-rest-api-with-the-zend-framework/)
- [Another guide](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)
- [And another](http://blogs.oracle.com/divyen/entry/developing_a_rest_apis_in)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a restful minimal framework, i recommend https://github.com/codeguy/Slim its fresh and works wonderful

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend who used http://getfrapi.com/ and he said that it worked well for him and his little API. I don't know if this is exactly what your looking for, but it looks like a stable framework for making REST APIs