# Library to write PHP web service for android consumption

Tags: php, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Framework for providing API access to website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603975/framework-for-providing-api-access-to-website)

I need to write a service in PHP. The server will be used by android/iphone clients through the url for example like this

```
http://www.myservice.com/query.php?param1=a&param2=2...
```

- The server will return data back
- The client will push data to server
- There can be large num of clients simultaneously accessing so the performance is key

I want to use the data format that is easily understood by my android client. In other words, I do not want to reinvent the wheel and create my own format and parsing, instead I would prefer to use any library if it exists. 
Is there a framework that I can use to abstract the communication mechanism for data get and push ?

Thanks, 
Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

I developed a class that is the PHP native SoapServer class' REST equivalent.

You just include the RestServer.php file and then use it as follows.

```
class Hello
{
  public static function sayHello($name)
  {
    return "Hello, " . $name;
  }
}

$rest = new RestServer(Hello);
$rest->handle();
```

Then you can make calls from Java like this:

```
http://myserver.com/path/to/api?method=sayHello&name=World
```

(Note that it doesn't matter what order the params are provided in the query string. Also, the param key names as well as the method name are case-insensitive.)

[Get it here](http://jakesankey.com/blog/2012/09/php-simple-rest-server/).

Answer (score 0):

Being the Author of Restler, I would like to suggest that you can try [Restler 3](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/tree/v3) for the following reasons

- It is specifically made for API creation
- It handles media type conversion for you and supports many media types including

  - JSON
  - Plist (both XML and Binary)
  - XML
- Comes with many [examples](http://bit.ly/r3-examples) to get started.
- Your API is automatically documented with [Restler API Explorer](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-API-Explorer)

Answer (score -1):

well,
Use mvc framework(yii, ci, ...)
 and from controller directly print `json_encode($object)`.

It will return json data to browser, and consume it anywhere(compuer, droid, iphone, ... , iron :D). the solution is json. just share object in json format, so anyone can map it into it's preferred obejct

here is something [something](http://docs.fuelphp.com/general/controllers/rest.html) you may have a look

Comment: Generally yes, but -1 for suggesting to print output directly from the controller. If you're going to use an MVC framework, practice proper MVC!

Comment: this is rest, there is not V, is this web site that should have V? V is for html. when did you see V is a part of restful service, actually in service there will not be any V. U will give request then u will get response in json, xml, soap, or whatever.

Comment: And that's wrong. The V is just as applicable to REST requests as it is to websites. Webpage data is rendered in HTML. RESTful data is rendered as JSON or XML. HTML and XML/JSON are both Vs.

Comment: Well, how do you do `JSON` in V, can you give example V for json? json is not something programmer will make by hand, like html(putting divs with it's class and id's). I would call it dataMapper, you do not have to have V, tons of libs that can generate xml, json,... from your serializable object directly without having any V

Comment: Yes, so? Nobody said the V has to consist of HTML templates. The view gets passed data from the model/controller and renders it into a form that is useful to the client. That can mean you are simply reformatting an array and then `json_encode` it. It can mean you are using an XML library to generate an XML document. Or it can mean you are using an HTML/PHP template to make a website. Just imagine the same controller action being used for both the website and AJAX/REST requests and the same data being output, just in different formats depending on the client's needs.

Comment: There can be a simple switch in the controller: `if ($request->isRest()) $view->load('foo/json/bar.php'); else $view->load('foo/html/bar.php');` You can reuse the same controller action which passes the same data around, just the view is different. (Not that this is necessarily the best way to do things all the time, but it illustrates the concept.)

Comment: Look here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api. And Question is what I will write inside the `ajax/foo/bar.php`? Just `json_encode($data)`? Why I can not write it simply from controller? ok anyway, I do not see any advantage of having V for rest. thanks for examples

Comment: In the link `_sendResponse()` is not written well, ok anyway. I had never have V for rest before

Comment: Yes, just `json_encode($data)` as the "V" is a possibility. More likely though your API has a fixed, defined, strict data format. The job of the view then is to output data in exactly that format. It takes the data from the model in whatever your internal format is and massages it into the specified format for the API output. Your internal data model may evolve and change over time. If you're just doing a straight `json_encode($modelData)` in the controller, you are coupling the API output to your internal data model, which can easily get you into hot water later on. Therefore: V.